# Problem with search Filter in my Database

Tags: android, search, realm, full-text-search

I have a search bar that search in all of my database.

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    psList = ps_da.searchBox(s);
    adapterPS = new AdapterPS(ActivityPS.this,psList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ActivityPS.this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPS);
    return false;
}
```

and i have a Alert dialog that filter my result that show in my recyclerview.

```
        imgFilter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActivityPS.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_filter_layout);
            Button btnfliter =dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncheckFilter);
            CheckBox chkActive = dialog.findViewById(R.id.chkActiveDirectory);
            CheckBox chkDNS = dialog.findViewById(R.id.chkDND);
            CheckBox chkDHCP = dialog.findViewById(R.id.chkDHCP);
            CheckBox chkVPN = dialog.findViewById(R.id.chkVPN);
            CheckBox IP = dialog.findViewById(R.id.IP);
            RadioGroup radioGroup = dialog.findViewById(R.id.radiogroupk);
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    RadioButton rd = group.findViewById(checkedId);
                    if (rd.isChecked()){
                        if (rd.getText().equals("Client")){
                            chkActive.setEnabled(false);
                            chkDHCP.setEnabled(false);
                            chkVPN.setEnabled(false);
                            chkDNS.setEnabled(false);
                        }else if (rd.getText().equals("All")){
                            chkActive.setEnabled(true);
                            chkDHCP.setEnabled(true);
                            chkVPN.setEnabled(true);
                            chkDNS.setEnabled(true);

                        }else if (rd.getText().equals("Server")){
                            chkActive.setEnabled(true);
                            chkDHCP.setEnabled(true);
                            chkVPN.setEnabled(true);
                            chkDNS.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            btnfliter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (!IP.isChecked()){
                        if (chkActive.isChecked()){
                            acvtiveDirectory = chkActive.getText().toString();
                        }if (chkDHCP.isChecked()){
                            DHCP =chkDHCP.getText().toString();
                        }if (chkDNS.isChecked()){
                            DNS = chkDNS.getText().toString();
                        }if (chkVPN.isChecked()){
                            VPN = chkVPN.getText().toString();
                        }   psList =ps_da.searchByFilter(acvtiveDirectory,DNS,DHCP,VPN);
                            adapterPS = new AdapterPS(ActivityPS.this,psList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPS);
                            adapterPS.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                    }else {
                        psList = ps_da.findAll();
                        adapterPS = new AdapterPS(ActivityPS.this,psList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPS);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

}
```

but I when I add my filter it correctly show on my recyclerview but when I wanna search between filtred result in the search bar it search in whole database.I want to search in the filtred range. Any Idea?

And thats my realm DA class for my PS object:

```
public RealmResults<PS> findAll(){
    pslist = myrealm.where(PS.class).findAll();
    return pslist;
}

public RealmResults<PS> searchBox(String s){
    pslist = myrealm.where(PS.class).contains("commandName",s, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
    return pslist;
}

public RealmResults<PS> searchByFilter(String Active,String DNS,String DHCP,String VPN){
    pslist = myrealm.where(PS.class).beginGroup().equalTo("commandName",Active)
            .or()
            .equalTo("commandName",DHCP)
            .or()
            .equalTo("commandName",DNS)
            .or()
            .equalTo("commandName",VPN)
            .endGroup().findAll();


    return pslist;
}
```

Comment: you need to save your state, if your filter checked or not, and then searchBox(String s) with filters. or manually search, iterate on the pslist returned from searchByFilter()

Answer (score 0):

In `onQueryTextChange` you create a new adapter each time.

You need to instantiate the adapter once and keep its reference in your activity, so you can set data to it and call `getFilter().filter("")` on it to filter data you did set.
To use filter in your adapter you can implement `Filterable`, but return your results in `performFiltering` method ([Filtering Realm object in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167999/1243048)).

Here is an example (didn't test it)

```java
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter<ArticleEntity> implements Filterable{

private RealmResults<ArticleEntity> items;
private RealmResults<ArticleEntity> filteredItems;
private ArticleFilter filter;

public MyAdapter(RealmResults<ArticleEntity> items) {
    this.items = items;
    filter = new ArticleFilter();
    filter.filter("");
}

public void setItems(RealmResults<ArticleEntity> items) {
    this.items = items;
    filter.filter("");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filteredItems.size();
}

@Override
public ArticleEntity getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filter;
}

private class ArticleFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        return new FilterResults();
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredItems = items.where()
                .equalTo("your_field", "value")
                .sort("name")
                .findAll();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

So your filtering based on your checkboxes should be done in the filter `publishResults` method.